# Creating a ruby gem requiring an API key from user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rubygems

I am building my first ruby gem for a service which requires the use of an API key from the user,
so I would like to know what should I do to let the user give his own API key to the gem when he installs it?

Thanks :)

Comment: IMHO it's better for the gem install to *not* need the API key, and instead have the user put the API key in a config file. For a good example of this, see the New Relic gem.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Do you have any resource where I could find examples? I don't really know where to look into the new relic gem, it's really big.. :\

Comment: Yes, you can install New Relic as usual. You won't need an API key. When you sign up for a New Relic free trial, New Relic sends you an API key and a sample config YML file. The variable is named "license_key" so you could likely search the gem source for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let users of your gem put the API key in `config/yourgem_config.yml`

```
# yourgem_config.yml
api_key: 1233456
```

From your gem, load this YAML file, and use the `api_key` that is specified.

Optionally fall back so some other sort of API access, when the config file can not be found, or provide a error message.

Optionally let the user configure the path to the config file.

Comment: btw, a rather simple example of a different approach (exposing a configuration object, and letting the user set configuration options through that) can be found in the Adyen gem. Have a look at these files. 
exposure: https://github.com/wvanbergen/adyen/blob/master/lib/adyen.rb 
config-object: https://github.com/wvanbergen/adyen/blob/master/lib/adyen/configuration.rb 
usage:
https://github.com/wvanbergen/adyen/blob/master/lib/adyen/api/simple_soap_client.rb